# Simple macro copying format, want to skip cells that already have format

Tags: excel, vba

I have this very simple macro that copies the interior fill from Column A of one sheet to Column D of another.

Does anyone have a link to an example that skips cells in the second (paste) sheet that already has interior fill?

```
Sub copyCombinedFormat()
'TO BE ADDED IN
' this copies the format for matching values in combined to the weekly report

    Worksheets("Combined").Activate
        Columns("A:A").Select
        Selection.copy
    
    Worksheets("Combined2").Activate
    Columns("D:D").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
            False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see any way around this besides a loop.

Comment: @BigBen ah rough

Comment: Not if you are pasting whole columns at once? The VBA simply executes a paste instruction that tells XL to paste the whole column. It doesn't subsequently verify each cell thereafter... So indeed, a loop running through each cell, or an algorithm that retrieves the ranges that already have particular properties?